# Nativescript Listview different behaviour on IOS

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using Nativscript-ui-listview, the RadListView component. In the list I display widgets that I have built my self. On Android there is no problem, they all get loaded and displayed as soon as i open the list. But on IOS some load after I scroll past them and then scroll back to them and some wont display at all. The left image is Android and the right image is IOS. The list shows three widgets, a Chart widget, map and a widget with numbers. How do I get them to show on IOS?

[image]
[image]

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-newlist',
  templateUrl: './new-widgets-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-widgets-list.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  moduleId: module.id,
})

export class NewListComponent implements OnInit {
  public title: String = 'Widgets';
  public widgetsListSubscription = new Subscription;
  public widgets$: ObservableArray < Widget > ;
  public _sourceDataItems: ObservableArray < Widget > ;
  public _sourceDataItems2: ObservableArray < Widget > ;
  public processing$ = new BehaviorSubject < boolean > (true);
  public listview: RadListView;
  public layout: ListViewLinearLayout;

  constructor(public page: Page,
    private readonly store: Store < AppState > ) {
    this.initData();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.widgets$ = new ObservableArray < Widget > ();
  }

  public get dataItems(): ObservableArray < Widget > {
    return this._sourceDataItems2;
  }

  private initData(): void {
    this._sourceDataItems = new ObservableArray < Widget > ();
    const data = this.store.pipe(
      select(getDisplayedWidgets),
      map(idmap => Object.values(idmap))
    );
    data.subscribe(list => this._sourceDataItems.push(list));
    this._sourceDataItems2 = this._sourceDataItems;
  }
}
```

```html
<GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
  <app-action-bar [title]="title"></app-action-bar>
  <RadListView [items]="dataItems" id="rlv">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <GridLayout columns="auto">
          <app-widgets-picker horizontalAlignment="left" [widget]="item"></app-widgets-picker>
        </GridLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
    <ListViewLinearLayout *appIfIos tkListViewLayout itemHeight="250"></ListViewLinearLayout>
  </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share a complete Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I've bypassed this kind of problem by using a repeater rather than a listview.  If this approach works for you, repeaters are much more predictable on iOS.

Comment: Can i use the repeater in an Angular project?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS the ListView should have a predefined size or otherwise it will either not occupy any space or lead to some side effects as dynamic row size is not supprted by design in ios U|X. I haved these kind of issue earlier. Providing the height to the items in row template fixed the issues for me.e.g.

```
<ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical" height="250">
        <GridLayout columns="auto" height="250">
          <app-widgets-picker horizontalAlignment="left" [widget]="item"></app-widgets-picker>
        </GridLayout>
      </StackLayout>
</ng-template>
```

Make sure you have height assigned in your `app-widgets-picker` component as well.

P.S. Yes, I noticed that you are using `ListViewLinearLayout` but that does not solve the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i got a better result with your example but i had the change the RadListView to a ListView. But the ListView does not seem to automatically update my widgets with new data as it comes. And if i scroll away from the chart widget and scroll back to it it just loads but nothing happens. The other items in the list loads in and disappears while scrolling. Not a very consistent behaviour.

Comment: If it is angular one then use ngOnChanges solves the purpose

Comment: should i refresh the listview OnChanges?

Comment: Make row item as component and refresh data look and feel on ngonchange

Comment: I don't understand how to do that? Is there a playground or a good example of this?

Answer (score 0):

So i have tried so many different things to solve this problem and I finally found one that works for both android and ios. It might not have all the fancy things built in as the ListView does but it works beautifully on both platforms. It updates the ui when the observable gets new data and there are no ui glitches.

The solution is to just use a ScrollView and ngFor to display the list items. I have only tried this with smaller amounts of lists items (10-20) and it loads very quick.

```html
<ScrollView orientation="vertical">
  <GridLayout rows="auto, auto">
    <StackLayout row="0">
      <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of obs$ | async" class="card">
        <app-widgets-picker horizontalAlignment="left" [widget]="item"></app-widgets-picker>
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This does not solve the issues that i'v been having with the LitView on ios but it works for the time being.

Comment: The ListView is virtualized which means that it can handle thousands of rows. It only creates GUI elements for whats inside the display area, and then changes out those elements when you scroll to simulate scrolling through a long list.

Comment: Yes I know, scrollview is not as good as a proper list view at showing bigger amounts of rows. But I could not get the list to work. And I need to get this app out to customers. And in this apps case the lists will never be very big. 

I would love the use the list view but I can't get it to work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

my data didn't show up on Android as it went down. I did as @Narendra said and executed the corresponding codes in the ngOnChanges function.

```
ngOnChanges(){
    if (this.item.profilePhoto === undefined) this.setAnonimProfilePhoto();
    if (!this.item.isOnline) this.userOfflineFromNow();
    this.getCityName();
}
```

@Narendra so thank you.